# Paypal Sandbox recurring payment with initial amount pending

Tags: php, paypal, sandbox

I'm using the PHP library [here](https://github.com/thenbrent/paypal-digital-goods) to create a new subscription profile. If I set an initial amount, the profile appears as "Pending".

Example:

```
Pending
Customer Mark Wally Verified
Profile start date Feb 18, 2013 | Profile ID I-BE824P6F9PER
```

On the other hand, if I set no initial payment amount, the profile will be "Active". I am setting the initial payment and the start date 1 month in the future since I want to bill monthly and get a payment right away.

I've already verified:

- Account is set to accept money in any currency
- The seller account has digital goods enabled (created via automated process)
- Both accounts are verified
- The buyer account has a credit card as well as a paypal balance
- Both accounts are US based
- I've tried with multiple accounts

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Code snippet to create the subscription that use the library listed above:

```
$subscription_details = array(
  'description'    => 'Premium membership: $4.95 every 30 days',
  'initial_amount' => '4.95',
  'amount'         => '4.95',
  'period'         => 'Day',
  'start_date'     => gmdate( 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s', strtotime( '+30 day' ) ),
  'frequency'      => '30'
);
```

Comment: What does your PHP look like for setting the payment and subscription?

Comment: I added my variables, everything else is default from the class. I don't think it's a problem with the code: The subscription gets created without any problems. The problem is the subscription profile is stuck in pending status forever.

Comment: I would imagine that the amount is only deducted on the next day, after which the state would go to "active"?

Comment: It's not -- the account is still pending after 2 weeks.

Comment: Perhaps it's still pending because you've set the start date 1 month in the future? Have you tested setting a start date of the next day and seeing if it then becomes active? You might need to set up a single one-off payment, and then the subscription after that.

Comment: I have tried to set the date to the next day, and nothing happens ever. No payment is ever made between the accounts whatever option is set.

Comment: Did you solve this? Having the exakt same issue, but using ruby API. The profile is set to PendingProfile when it has an initial amount, activeprofile without initial amount. Tried a lot of different configs

Comment: There is nothing to solve -- the sandbox is just really slow, sometimes it took a couple days for the profile to become active and send the IPN. In other words, sandbox isn't good to test these functions at all, just go live and refund a couple tests. Even live sometimes takes a bit of time... I've seen it take a few hours sometimes, so don't go crazy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just in case someone else has this trouble, my findings are:

There is nothing to solve -- the sandbox is just really slow, sometimes it took a couple days for the profile to become active and send the IPN. In other words, sandbox isn't good to test these functions at all, just go live and refund a couple tests. Even live sometimes takes a bit of time... I've seen it take a few hours sometimes, so don't go crazy.

Comment: wow that's crazy! Why the hell can't you see a list of pending IPN's and then force send? =[ I can't believe how bad Paypal is at this!!

Comment: When you submit a CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API call you set when the Profile is created. So if you set the start date to be a few days in the future you wouldn't get an IPN post until then. Is there an example Recurring Profile that was created and didn't generate an IPN post right away?

Comment: I have just tested this myself. The time and date started is set to now, but I haven't received an IPN (nor is it in my IPN history). I'm happy to provide my test account details on this. Currently on hold for 20 minutes after being redirected 4 times now...

Comment: Finally got through. Phone support for technical issues is not supported in the UK. I must submit a ticket and wait for them to get back to me. Not very helpful when you're trying to develop stuff. Moving to a different provider where possible for future projects, a provider who I can actually speak to on the phone!

Comment: @PayPal_Patrick An example which didn't generate an IPN post right away... Profile ID  I-FPUW8G5NEDA2 (on sandbox)

Comment: (Profile ID: I-FPUW8G5NEDA2)
(Message ID: 4WN84124DE639943N)
(Profile created: Aug 5, 2013 03:37:26 PDT)
(IPN was created: Aug 5, 2013 08:17:14 PDT)
A five hour difference is bad. I'm going to test this out on my own, get some examples, and reach out to the Sandbox team.

Comment: @PayPal_Patrick Just attempted this right now. Sandbox was down for a few minutes this morning so I guess they deployed some updates. IPN for initial payment was sent before I could go check the status. If they deployed a fix, then it seems to have worked =] Thanks. (@relequestual on twitter btw)

Comment: Incredible, I had created support tickets with paypal back then and was getting the run around and just gave up on the sandbox. :O Hopefully @PayPal_Patrick fixed it up for everyone now :)

Comment: There are large efforts in making the Live and Sandbox IPN posts more stable and consistent.

Comment: @ruinernix Do you have a twitter? I'd be interested to hear how you handled testing this stuff in the end? Project testing is still delayed for me, having to wait a day to test any changes, meaning most of my code is coded blind =/

Comment: I did delayed testing and when things seemed to be working I put it live and tested live. Lots of logging involved, and you can resend IPN from live so it makes things easier. I don't really use twitter, sorry :O

Comment: Thanks for the info! full paypal log and ipn logs and application logs in order. Should have even more advanced logging on the live site too =] Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

From PayPal doco:

"By default, PayPal does not activate the profile if the initial payment amount fails. To override this default behavior, set the FAILEDINITAMTACTION field to ContinueOnFailure. If the initial payment amount fails, ContinueOnFailure instructs PayPal to add the failed payment amount to the outstanding balance due on this recurring payment profile.

If you do not set FAILEDINITAMTACTION or set it to CancelOnFailure, PayPal creates the recurring payment profile. However, PayPal places the profile into a pending status until the initial payment completes. If the initial payment clears, PayPal notifies you by Instant Payment Notification (IPN) that it has activated the pending profile. If the payment fails, PayPal notifies you by IPN that it has canceled the pending profile"

from https://cms.paypal.com/mx/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPRecurringPayments, just below Table 6.