# paypal recurring payment pending status?

Tags: php

I have been searching and reading up about this issue for hours now and I do not have a clue why no one has an answer to this apart from changing the provider etc which is not wanted.

I also found this [Paypal Sandbox recurring payment with initial amount pending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447200/paypal-sandbox-recurring-payment-with-initial-amount-pending)

which is the exact same issue that i have right now and there seems to be someone called "*PayPal_Patrick* " who replied to that question but they've removed all their comments for some reason!

any way, I am just trying to figure out why the first initial paypal recurring payment shows as *pending*!

*I get the IPN response and my IPN enters the data into mysql database as it should but the payment status shows as pending!*

when I look into the paypal sandbox account, I see the payment status as pending too. so there must be something that stops the paypal to create the recurring profile immediately!

here is my simple form that will allow the user to create a recurring payment:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="mysandboxemail@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Return to The Store">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value=" <?php echo $actual_link ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="This is a custom field!!!">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="ACCOUNT UPGRADE">

<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="5.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1"> 
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

could someone please help me out with this issue?

Thanks

Comment: whats with the downvotes?

Comment: I'm sure there are some people from paypal patrolling the stackoverfllow but i don't know why when it comes to helping people, they seem to hide like "rats" in every hole they find!!!!!!! their own documentation is useless, their support forums are useless and they clearly have links to STO from their own site so why not replying to something that's needed some answers to?!

Comment: You know man, its rare when your question will not be downvoted. Even good questions are downvoted for no reason, so don't take that personally.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is for future reference:...

All you have to do is to change the settings of your Paypal account so it accepts payment from all currencies.

Comment: yeah, well, currency is the same... how is this one of the most-given answers? It is an edge case that currencies differ anyways